# Merging xpath generated lists, Python, lxml

Tags: python, xml, list, xpath, lxml

I am currently scraping an xml file for some data and I need help merging 3 lists with values generated from 3 xpath calls.:

Code:

```
   import urllib.request
    import lxml.etree as ET   

    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    tree = ET.parse(opener.open('https://nordfront.se/feed'))
```

The data i am interested in:

```
>>> tree.xpath("/rss/channel/item/title/text()")
['Klistermärkesuppsättning i Trollhättan', 'Dror Feiler vill inte betala sina böter – spelar judekortet', 'Gruppvåldtäkt: Media döljer att afrikaner är gärningsmän — kallar dem ”svenskar”', 'Nordfronts läsare: Gyllene grynings valresultat var en framgång', 'Karikatyrtävling över ”förintelsen” i Iran', 'Nytt födelseformulär: Är mamman som fött barn kvinna eller man?', 'Kampsportsträning i Stockholm', 'Nytt projekt för nationella kvinnor!', 'Svenskt företag opererar in mikrochip i anställda', 'Utbildning i Göteborg']
>>> tree.xpath("/rss/channel/item/link/text()")
['https://www.nordfront.se/klistermarkesuppsattning-trollhattan.smr', 'https://www.nordfront.se/dror-feiler-vill-inte-betala-sina-boter-spelar-judekortet.smr', 'https://www.nordfront.se/gruppvaldtakt-svenskar-sager-media-afrikaner-sager-vittnen.smr', 'https://www.nordfront.se/veckans-fraga-var-gyllene-grynings-valresultat-en-framgang.smr', 'https://www.nordfront.se/karikatyrtavling-forintelsen-iran.smr', 'https://www.nordfront.se/nytt-fodelseformular-ar-mamman-som-fott-barn-kvinna-eller-man.smr', 'https://www.nordfront.se/kampsportstraning-stockholm-15.smr', 'https://www.nordfront.se/nytt-projekt-nationella-kvinnor.smr', 'https://www.nordfront.se/svenskt-foretag-opererar-in-mikrochip-i-anstallda.smr', 'https://www.nordfront.se/utbildning-goteborg.smr']
>>> tree.xpath("/rss/channel/item/pubDate/text()")
['Mon, 02 Feb 2015 14:00:37 +0000', 'Mon, 02 Feb 2015 13:25:07 +0000', 'Mon, 02 Feb 2015 12:45:27 +0000', 'Mon, 02 Feb 2015 09:30:38 +0000', 'Sun, 01 Feb 2015 21:15:11 +0000', 'Sun, 01 Feb 2015 19:40:12 +0000', 'Sun, 01 Feb 2015 19:30:13 +0000', 'Sun, 01 Feb 2015 19:00:31 +0000', 'Sun, 01 Feb 2015 15:30:08 +0000', 'Sun, 01 Feb 2015 15:00:20 +0000']
```

Now its time to structure the data so that I can put the data into a database, each *item* in the xml file will represent one column in the database. **My problem is that I currently have information from each *item* split up into 3 different *lists*.**

I would like your help on how I can merge these lists together in a good way, something like:

```
Items Object => "item[0]" => "title" => "Title 1 text ..." "link" => "http://www...." "pubDate" => "Mon, 02 Feb 2015 14:00:37" "item[1]" => "title" => "Title 2 text ..." "link" => "http://www...." "pubDate" => "Mon, 02 Feb 2015 14:00:38"   ..
```

Would be very happy if someone could demonstrate on how I would accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), you will get a list (or an iterator if you use Python 3.x) of tuples:

```
records = zip(
    tree.xpath("/rss/channel/item/title/text()"),
    tree.xpath("/rss/channel/item/link/text()"),
    tree.xpath("/rss/channel/item/pubDate/text()")
)

# records => [
#    ('Klistermärkesuppsättning i Trollhättan',
#     'https://www.nordfront.se/klistermarkesuppsattning-trollhattan.smr',
#     'Mon, 02 Feb 2015 14:00:37 +0000'),
#    ('Dror Feiler vill inte betala sina böter – spelar judekortet',
#     'https://www.nordfront.se/dror-feiler-vill-inte-betala-sina-boter-spelar-judekortet.smr',
#     'Mon, 02 Feb 2015 12:45:27 +0000'),
#    ....
# ]
```

Comment: Thanks falsetru, this looks very flexible, however I wonder if there is any way to name each value (title, link, pubDate), so that I know which value to insert into which column, maybe you would retrieve them using [0], [1] and [2] ?

Comment: @Toothfairy, `[{'title': title, 'link': link, 'pubdate': pubdate} for title, link, pubdate in zip(...)]` Something like this (which will give you a list of dictionaries)?

Comment: @Toothfairy, Or: `[{'title': item.find('title').text, 'link': item.find('link').text, 'pubdate': item.find('pubDate').text} for item in tree.xpath("/rss/channel/item")]`